# Sniffing window messages in-process

Tags: winapi

I'm not very familiar with writing for Win32 directly, so please bear with me.

I need to write a plugin in C for an application (After Effects) that does certain things like accessing the clipboard.

I'm wondering if it could also sniff keyboard strokes from the message loop so that it allows me to implement my own keyboard shortcuts, something the application doesn't allow extending cleanly. That would be very important in my case.

I do have the main application window handle - you get that simply from the API.

Can I register a callback in Windows to be called on each message-loop event for me to call PeekMessage or something?

Comment: Don't reimplement [`RegisterHotKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx).

Comment: Depending on the application maybe you'd be better off using something like AutoHotkey for this rather than coding it yourself?

Comment: @JonathanPotter That may indeed be an option also, I will have a look at this - thank you.

Comment: @IInspectable RegisterHotKey posts event in the message queue on certain keyboard strokes. This has little to do with my problem of not getting hold of the messages in the queue in the first place.

Comment: To intercept messages, look at [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx)

Comment: @John You should have clearly stated, that your plugin does not provide a graphical UI. If it does, you can register a hotkey. If it doesn't, set up a message hook (`WH_MESSAGE`) as suggested by Remy. Whatever you do, don't accept Kirill's answer - it  ain't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the function `SetWindowSubclass`. Read about it here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: -1 Subclassing a window replaces its window procedure. Consequently, this replacement procedure only receives messages, that make it to the window in question. Messages that are not dispatched, or messages that are dispatched to another window will be missed. For this specific scenario a [`WH_GETMESSAGE` hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) is more appropriate.

Comment: @IInspectable, what you are saying sounds like a better answer. It would be more appropriate to post a second answer in this situation instead of offending. The original post is not crisp clear on what is available and what and where should be processed. It may easily happen that my recommendation will be enough. Since the answer was accepted, it looks like my recommendation worked. I posted technically correct info that worked and helped. So, what is wrong? I may remove this comment in a couple of days.

Comment: There is nothing technically wrong in my answer. Subclassing can be used for filtering messages in process, especially when the target window handle is available. One of advantages of this approach that it is relatively easy to learn and implement. Especially when developer is not familiar with Win32 details.

Comment: Subclassing a window is anything but easy, even with the infrastructure introduced with version 6 of the common controls. Setting up an in-process hook, on the other hand, is straight forward. Posting a link without providing a rationale, when to use this API, is, at the very least, incomplete. Given that this question particularly asks for hotkey handling (which is more often than not implemented without dispatching messages) makes this answer - in general - technically incorrect.